# Django Crud for a Model, Need to Copy for Big no of Models, Need DRY Concept

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have crud for model but i need to copy this for big no of models.. I Need Your Recommendations to minimize the copy past. Thanks
And kindly dont recomment django admin, i want to use my own theme.

I hvae model as:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

And ModelForm as:

```
class BoardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Board
        fields = [
            'name',
            'description',
        ]
```

I have Django Url Patterns as shown below:

```
url(r'^board/$', board_crud, name='board_crud'),
url(r'^board/(?P<pk>\d+)$', board_crud, name='board_update'),
```

And i Have View:

```
def board_crud(request, pk=None):
    objects = Board.objects.filter()
    if pk is not None:
        object = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)
        form = BoardForm(request.POST or None, instance=object)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = BoardForm()
            return redirect('board_crud')
        return render(request, "crud/boards.html", {'form': form, 'object_list': objects})
    else:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = BoardForm()
        else:
            form = BoardForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                instance.save()
                form = BoardForm()
                messages.success(request, 'Record Added Successfully')
        return render(request, "crud/boards.html", {'form': form, 'object_list': objects})
```

And Template with form Maker and Table:

```
{% for field in form %}
        <section class="col col-6">
            <label class="label">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
            <label class="input">
                {{ field }}
            </label>
        </section>
{% endfor %}



<table id="tbl" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Board Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for object in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{% url "board_update" object.id %}">{{ object.name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ object.description }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: [Django Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/) is great for this kind of use case. You get CRUDs out of the box. If using Django Admin is not an option, [Class-Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/) are great for reusability. I'm afraid there is no short answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms)

Should abstract enough out to define the views very easily.